# Books similar in nature to Logic and Theism by Jordan Sobel?

Tags: logic, reference-request, introduction-to-philosophy

I've recently been reading "Logic and Theism" by Jordan Sobel and have found it to be fascinating. The two primary things I like about it are:

1. The book primarily focuses on analyzing the arguments of others through the lens of symbolic logic so as to expose ambiguities and understand precisely if or where there could be issues in their argument. It feels less like Sobel is trying to convince me of something and more that he's trying to take me along with his analysis, which I enjoy (though it is certainly clear that Sobel is an atheist).
2. It has helped massively in giving me a kind of logical, conceptual framework to think about a problem (existence of God) that would otherwise be so large and steeped in tradition and argumentative trickery so as to feel impossible to make progress in. The logic in the text is being used to assist with thinking and could be used practically as a mindset in approaching philosophical discussions.

Are there any other Logic and ___ type books that use symbolic logic to analyze problems/arguments in various other areas of philosophy that follow the same general spirit as Sobel that you can recommend? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just found [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/i25ecy/are_there_any_good_responses_to_jh_sobels_work/) that it's considered a pretty final book, so what you ask for may be difficult to find.

Comment: Interesting. If is such a singular work, then I could extend the request more generally to "extensive usages of symbolic logic in other areas of philosophy."